# Confused about interfaces

Tags: kotlin

This code works when I only use objects, however when I use a val instead of an object the IDE gives an error : Class 'Success' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member. Any help would be appreciated.

This works fine:

```
    data class Success(val photos: List<MarsPhoto>) : MarsUiState
    object Error : MarsUiState
    object Loading: MarsUiState
}
```

This doesn't

```
sealed interface MarsUiState {
    data class Success(val photos: List<MarsPhoto>) : MarsUiState
    object Error : MarsUiState
    val Loading: MarsUiState
}
```

Comment: In the second example, you are declaring implementations of the `MarsUiState` type to have a property named `Loading` of type `MarsUiState`. And you haven't implemented that property in the `Success` class.

Comment: It feels like you expect `val` and `object` to do similar things. They do not.

Comment: Why did you expect `val` and `object` to work the same way?

Comment: @Jorn I'm quite new to coding as a whole, I'm currently learning android development, and I came across this code in one of the codelabs of the course I'm learning from. They variables inside the interface basically represent whether retrieving photos is loading, worked, or didn't work. What I don't understand is why use objects to represent those states, why not just use normal val values? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val` defines a property on the interface type, while `object` defines a new type, not a variable/property.

Actually, the thing that might confuse you about objects is that their name not only defines a type, but also a way to access the only value of that type. So when `Loading` is declared as an `object`, `MarsUiState.Loading` is *both* a type and a value, and can be used in the Kotlin syntax in places that expect a type (like the parameter types in a function definition, or the return type of a function), and *also* in places that expect an expression/value, like the right-hand side of an assignment (`val x = expression`), or the argument of a function call (`myFun(expression)`).

Using `val` here would mean that the `MarsUiState` has a *property* named `Loading` and thus any instance of `MarsUiState` has to have a value for that property (and the `Success` subtype doesn't respect that, so you get an error). But that doesn't make any sense anyway.

The point here is to say that instances of the `MarsUiState` type can be of one of 3 subtypes: either `Success`, `Error`, or `Loading`. So all those 3 things must be types too (either classes or objects - which are kinda classes too, they just have only one instance).